# GeckoFx 45 running not connected to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, geckofx

I am having a strange issue and am not sure how to figure out what is happening. I am developing an Add-In for Revit to display a web page in the dock panels. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/using-the-gecko-web-browser-in-a-c-winforms-project/) for using GeckoFx45 in WPF. Everything works fine while I am debugging with Visual Studio. If I quit debugging and run the same dll disconnected from Visual Studio, GeckoFx45 stops at Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");

I haven't recompiled, just running without Visual Studio attached and debugging. Since it works while debugging, I'm not sure how to figure out what is wrong.

If it makes a difference, I am using the most recent GeckoFx45 64 bit NuGet. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geckofx45.64/

Comment: Do you get any errors at `Xpcom.Initialize()`? When you run it 'without VS', do you use the files from your debug folder (the same that Studio would use), or do you have them somewhere else?

Comment: I don't change anything, and run the debug files in the same location except that VS is not attached.  I don't receive any error. I'm not sure how to enable logging on GeckoFx to see what the problem is, but my simple logging stop just prior to 'Xpcom.Initialize()' It just quietly doesn't initialize.

Comment: Ok... Use the Application.DispatcherUnhandledException Event to catch any unhandled exception, log it somehow and let us know what it says. If still no error, then ensure whether a next line of code is being executed.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by Changing the Initialize to an absolute path to the Firefox folder.  That seems to have fixed it.